# What happens when i call stopSelf in onDestroy method?

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle, android-service-binding

I have such a method implementation and I want to understand what will happen when this method is called. Could you give me a hint

```
override fun onDestroy() {
        Timber.d("$this: onDestroy")
        stopSelf()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

Comment: you should see the declaration of stopSelf() method in order to understand the behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onDestroy()` should only be called by Android when the `Service` has already stopped. Android won't call `onDestroy()` if the `Service` is running. If you call `stopSelf()` in `onDestroy()` it should just do nothing, as the `Service` is already stopped.